# plug-in org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui was unable to load class

Tags: eclipse, maven, sonarqube, m2eclipse

I had made an maven project and it worked fine. 
Then I installed plugins 
  EclEmma Java Code Coverage,
  PHP Development Tools (PDT),
  Eclipse.orgSonarQube

Then I worked on some other project. When I again wanted to create an maven project,it threw the following error window which said

```
The selected wizard could not be started
reason
plug-in org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui was unable to load class
org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal wizards.MavenProjectWizard
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Removed SonarQube plugin .This solved the issue.
Now it works all fine.
But is there any other solution to this problem since I have to use sonar.

Comment: Wow. I removed SonarQube and a couple of other plugins, and problem disappeared!

Answer (score 1):

Click on eclipse `help` tab and open `installation details` search sonar and remove all related plugins.

Answer (score 0):

That's not quite the right characterization of what it says on the page,Please check your .log file `/path/workspace/.metadata/`

Find the correct plugin which is causing this problem and update to compatible version of the plugin with eclipse version.
To find the hidden files in the workspace use `Ctrl+H`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I've tried so many solutions. But what I did to solve the problem, is that I just upgraded my Eclipse IDE (2019-06 to 2020-03) by following these steps (from https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F) :

> 1. You first need to add the new release's repository as follows: 
>          1-1. Window > Preferences > Install/Update > Available Software Sites
>          1-2. Click 'Add'
>          1-3. Enter the URL https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-03/
>          1-4. Click 'Ok'
>
>    2. Help > Check for Updates
>    3. If updates are found, proceed through the install wizard and restart the IDE when 
>         prompted. Otherwise, read carefully the error message to find out which component 
>         is conflicting and establish your resolution strategy.
>    4. Note that the start splash screen may be cached and will not necessarily be 
>         updated to the latest version after the IDE is restarted. Performing a full 
>         relaunch should display the new version number.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what you really need to do is remove m2e from your eclipse, shutdown and restart eclipse, and then add m2e back in.

Also you could install websphere from eclipse marketplace and that will fix it as well.   There is absolutely no need to clear out .metedata as that is a really hard.

If installing websphere from eclipse marketplace use the highest version possible but not liberty unless you want that.